# Date' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: django, django-models

I am using 3 Date-Fields in models.py and after makemigrations, I did migrate and turned into an error.

Error:

d

```
> jango.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'Date' value has an invalid
> date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

Even I removed all the model fields on models.py file and then migrated, but still giving the error.

Please anyone who knows the best solution?

Comment: The invalid date format exists in migrations file. You need to fix it or remove it carefully

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. How can I remove that migration file?

Comment: Do you care about the data in your database?  If you are just testing, there is an easy fix to this.

Comment: Yes. I am not testing but making  a website which uses database.

Comment: Can I revert the last migration?

Comment: you say "making a website".  Does that mean you haven't deployed?

Comment: Yes. In development phase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a shot in the dark:

Try reverting your last migration with the following:

```
./manage.py migrate myapp xxxx_previous_migration
```

where `xxxx` is your previous migration.  If you are unsure of what your previous migration was, you can run `./manage.py showmigrations myapp` to see a list of all migrations made in `myapp`